# Giving a line break in echo with a wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to give a line break in the following echo statement.

```
   <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Show the reply and apply the formatting function on the content
                                     */

                                    echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $row->post_content ) );
```

I have tried to use "\n" and 
 at the start of echo like :

```
    <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Show the reply and apply the formatting function on the content
                                     */

                                    echo "\n"wpautop( wp_kses_post( $row->post_content ) );
```

But after this the page does not load.

Can someone suggest something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about trying <br> as the browser reads html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
* Show the reply and apply the formatting function on the content
*/

echo "\n" . wpautop( wp_kses_post( $row->post_content ) );
```

You need to use a concatination character(dot symbol).

`\n` = unix linebreak, not html, use `<br>` for html linebreak

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
/* Show the reply and apply the formatting function on the content */

echo '<br>' . wpautop( wp_kses_post( $row->post_content ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to concatenate the string with a DOT `.`:

```
<?php
/*** Show the reply and apply the formatting function on the content***/
                                 */
echo "\n" . wpautop( wp_kses_post( $row->post_content ) );
?>
```